# Getting payload from an ENIP protocol WinPcap C#

Tags: c#, udp, ethernet, winpcap

I'm not too familiar with protocols, so I might be wrong. But when I use WireShark to monitor my packet capture, it says that the packet came in through ENIP protocol. Although, there is another tab within it for UDP protocol as well.

I'm programming in C# and trying to get the packet payload and parse it to a string. Wireshark shows this payload in the window when the packet is received as hex, so I want something similar to that. How can I use Winpcap and C# to do this? Maybe there's some documentation that I haven't seen yet, but I've searched the internet for this a lot already.

Here's the code I have so far for packet handler if that helps:

```
   public void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
    {
        IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
        UdpDatagram udp = ip.Udp;

        // get payload
        byte[] payload = udp.Payload.ToMemoryStream().ToArray();
        data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payload);
    }
```